# Asymptotic expression for Fourier Transform of $e^{-|x|^n}$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, exponential-function

I've been trying to find an expression for the Fourier transform of the function:

$e^{-|x|^n}$

I believe it doesn't have a closed form, but someone did get an expression in terms of an infinite series:

[The Fourier transform of $ e^{-|x|^\alpha}, \alpha>0. $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068522/the-fourier-transform-of-e-x-alpha-alpha0?rq=1)

It's a nice solution, but I was looking for something I could evaluate numerically, so I can't use that expression since it's an infinite sum. I tried cutting the series up to the 100th term, but after a certain number of terms my computer cannot longer handle the expression.  I was wondering if someone could suggest me a way of getting an approximate expression that doesn't require an infinite sum.

Since I'm dealing with a negative exponential, I would expect that my integral converges to something. I just don't know what approach to take.

During my search I also found this post where they talk about something called the "**Method of Steepest Descent**", but I'm not familiarized with that method, so I'm unsure if it will help me at all.

[Asymptotic behaviours from Fourier transforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794619/asymptotic-behaviours-from-fourier-transforms)

I've been scratching my head with this, but I can't find a way around this.

Thanks.

Comment: The main asymptotic term comes directly. Given that $x^n\to 0$ at $x<1$ and $x^n\to \infty$ at $x>1$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|^n}e^{2\pi ik x}dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-|x|^n}\cos(2\pi k x)dx=2\int_0^1\cos(2\pi k x)dx+o(1)$$

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer the question!

Comment: That's correct but only if you consider $n \rightarrow \infty$ right? if $n$ is a value somewhere between 1 and 2, should we still consider this argument, correct? I believe not, because that would be saying that the integral of a gaussian is the same as the integral of $$e^{-|x|}$$ I was hoping to get something that would give me a distinction between Fourier Transforms depending on the $n$ exponent.

Comment: Yes, it is valid for $n\to\infty$; for just $n>1$ there will be correction terms. I'm not sure that we can get these corrections in a nice form...

Comment: I see. Thank you. I appreciate your answers.